# Why was this question closed, "Apple Gaming Console"

Tags: discussion, closing

Why was this question closed?

For ease of reference, I'm going to duplicate the question within the question, but here's a link to the question [Apple Gaming Console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/32148/apple-gaming-console).

> **Question title:** Apple Gaming Console
>
> **Question body:**
> In the current market, what are the pros and cons of Apple releasing
> it's own gaming console?
>
> It's possible that the [Apple TV](http://www.apple.com/appletv/) already does this, but I'm unable
> to find controllers that support Apple AppStore games, or for that
> matter support of the AppStore games on Apple TV.
>
> **Question Tags:** controllers, consoles, apple

Comment: ...You guys don't think closing it is enough?  You had to downvote it too?

Comment: @GnomeSlice I didn't down vote it myself, but any question which is valid to close is also valid to down vote.

Comment: @GnomeSlice - I agree that those downvotes are not justified. The question was clear and some research effort was shown. I do, however, think the closing was correct.

Comment: We don't have a magic crystal ball, that's why :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason I closed it is that it's a discussion question, not a Q&A question. Due to this it is not a good fit to our site.

From the [FAQ](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask):

> What kind of questions should I not ask here?
>
> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual
>   problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the
>   usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

Something else to consider is that speculation questions are also off-topic:

> Please note, however, that site policies prohibit questions of the
>   following types:
>   [...]
>
> - Speculation of the future of the industry and of upcoming releases

Comment: +1 @Wipqozn: Great, thanks, makes sense.

Comment: If the question was rephrased to be is it possible to use the Apple TV as a console, and if so, what are the pros and cons of using it as a console... would you vote to reopen the question; or would that still not address the concerns you may have?

Comment: @blunders - I would definitely consider your revised question to be  on-topic.

Comment: Asking if it is "possible to use the Apple TV as a console" is a perfectly valid question. Asking about the pros and cons is iffy, since it could easily lead to subjective answers. However, I would cast a re-open vote if you rephrased the question as such.

Comment: @sjohnston: The question has been updated, if either of you have additional feedback, just let me know. Again, thank you!

Comment: @Wipqozn: See comment to **sjohnston** above, thanks!